# getting validate.js to work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble getting my simple contact form to validate and am not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've stripped the code almost exactly out of a stand alone demo and followed the tut. What's wrong with my code?

[Tut & demo](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jquery/form_validation/index.html)

**In the head:** *Updated Attempt*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

**Initiating, almost right before the closing** `</head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  SubmittingForm=function() {
    alert("The form has been validated.");
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fvujq-form1").validate({
      submitHandler:function(form) {
        SubmittingForm();
      },
      rules: {
        name: "required", // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
        email: {          // compound rule
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        url: {
          url: true
        },
        comment: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        comment: "Please enter a comment."
      }
    });
  });

  jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "selectNone",
    function(value, element) {
      if (element.value == "none") {
        return false;
      }
      else return true;
    },
    "Please select an option."
  );

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fvujq-form2").validate({
      submitHandler:function(form) {
        SubmittingForm();
      },
      rules: {
        sport: {
          selectNone: true
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Close to the bottom of page, form markup:**

```
<p style="font-style:italic; font-size:12px; font-weigh: normal; margin-top: -89px;     margin-left: 33px;">Contact me written in a different language.</p> <img src="http://www.cameroncashwell.com/imgs/pointing-left.png" style="float: right; margin-right: 140px; margin-top: -89px;">

<div class="form-div"> 
    <form id="fvujq-form1" style="font-size:22px; color:#333;" method="post" action="">
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">URL</span><input type="text" name="url" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Your Comment *</span><textarea name="comment"></textarea></div>
      <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Also - where would I call my email address for the contact form's contents to be sent?

Comment: Try loading jquery just one time. `jquery-1.3.2.min.js` **or** `jquery-latest.js`. And load jquery before the validate-plugin.

Comment: Still nothing - above I edited the Q with how I just attempted calling the jQuery in head. - any other suggestions?

Comment: your link to jquery validate is incorrect http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js is unreachable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. Your link to the Validate plugin is broken. Try using one from a CDN (like Microsoft's) instead:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Decide which version of jQuery you want to use. Right now, you're loading 1.3.2 (a pretty old version) and the latest version (1.7.1). I would stick with the latest version unless you have a specific reason not to. Here it's also smart to use a CDN:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. Make sure the scripts are loaded in the right order (jQuery, then jQuery Validate). If you place validate before jQuery, your validate code will not work:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   ```

Besides those issues, your actual JavaScript looks good.

Comment: I realized the second part of my Q - should be a separate question, so I made it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467486/how-to-make-my-contact-form-send-me-email (If you wanna stack those SO points haha)