# What is needed in php file to send this html form from a template

Tags: php, forms, email, submit, send

I know very little about contact forms and php.

I am building a website from a template and it has this form.

Can you please tell me what code to put in contact.php to send over entered information.

And also what email will it send from?

And where do I determine what email address it sends to?

THANK YOU!

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="contactform">

                <div>
                <p>Send us a message</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="Phone Number" type="text" id="Phone Number" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Subject</label>
                <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject"  value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="50"  id="message" ></textarea><br /><br />
                </div>

                <div>
                <input type="submit"  value="Submit" class="button">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button">
                </div>


            </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make my contact form send me Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467486/how-to-make-my-contact-form-send-me-email)

Comment: @SeanBone Not really what? You'd rather encourage lazy folks and lackluster research by providing the 100th tutorial and code dump here?

Comment: @mario Not really as in it's not actually a duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..

```
<form method="get" action="contact.php" id="contactform" name="contactform">

                <div>
                <p>Send us a message</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" id="Phone Number" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Subject</label>
                <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject"  value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="50"  id="message" ></textarea><br /><br />
                </div>

                <div>
                <input type="submit"  value="Submit" class="button">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button">
                </div>


            </form>
```

Your php file

```
<?php
                if (isset($_REQUEST['contactform']))
                {
                    echo $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
                    echo $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
                    echo $PhoneNumber = $_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'];
                    echo $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
                    echo $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

                }
                ?>
```

use this code to send email

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have validated the form input (if necessary), you should generate a string and then use the [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to send an email.

```
// contact.php
if (isset($_REQUEST['contactform'])) {
     # validate the form's input if necessary

     $message = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\nPhone No.:" . $_POST['Phone Number'] . "\nMessage:" . $_POST['message'];

     mail ('you@example.com', 'Contact form:' . $_POST['subject'], $message, "From: {$_POST['email']}");
}
```